Why can't the VESTA recognise the charge information of CHGCAR? And why there are negative values in my CHGCAR?
I carried out static calculation on a semiconductor surface structure containing defects and wanted to analyze its CHGCAR and ELFCAR, but I found that there were negative values in CHGCAR, and when I opened these two files with VESTA, only the structure information was displayed, VESTA could not read the charge information. VESTA seems to have no problem because it can open other structures of CHGCAR.The CHGCAR and ELFCAR files look normal with no missing data.
There is my INCAR，
  SYSTEM = system
  ISTART = 0         
  ICHARG = 2         
  ALGO   = Normal     
  ENCUT  = 650.0
  PREC   = Accurate
  ISMEAR = 0     
  SIGMA  = 0.05
  LREAL  = .False.
  NELM   = 300
  NELMIN = 6
  LORBIT = 11
  ISYM   = -1
  NSW    = 0
  LWAVE  = .TRUE.                       
  LCHARG = .TRUE.                    
  LELF   = .TRUE. 
  IBRION =  -1  
  ISIF   =  2 
  EDIFF  = 1.0E-6
  EDIFFG = -1.0E-2   
  NCORE  = 48
  NPAR   = 8
  GGA    = PE 


From the vasp input docs for ADDGRID: "Fourier smoothing, which is in essence used for the augmentation densities, is generally less problematic, but it can also result in negative density in real space."  Also see here: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Question_Why_is_convergence_to_the_ionic_groundstate_so_slow?
